# Grunt uglify - use existing minified file version

Tags: bower, yeoman, minify, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I used yeoman to scaffold an angular app and I'm trying to figure out how to use the existing minified file version of the lib in the bower_components folder rather than minifying it in my build process.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use bower-installer which is a node package to control which files to be copied to your lib folder from the downloaded distribution package folder.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-installer

I followed below steps to select which files to be copied to my lib folder

1) Install bower-installer 
    `npm install -g bower-installer`

2) Edit bower.json configuration file and specify path

3) Run bower-installer from terminal

Comment: This gives me a place to start, thanks. Too bad I need to add the minified files myself as it's not an automatic process.